# Two stage least squares regression with biomial response variable

Tags: r

Hi I'd like to run two stage least squares regression with binomial response variable.
For continuous response variable, I use "tsls" option from R package "sem".

Here are my commands and want to know I'm doing this right.

(x: endogenous variable, z: instrumental variable, y: response variable (0 or 1))

```
xhat<-lm(x~z)$fitted.values

R<-glm(y~xhat, family=binomial)

R$residuals<-c(y - R$coef[1]+x*R$coef[2])
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why you need to do this in two steps. Doesn't `R<-glm(y~z, family=binomial)` give you what you need? And why do you want to change the residuals element of the model object?

Comment: I read that this is the usual process in two-stage least squares method (instrumental variable analysis). To change the residuals element is for the adjustment for the residuals.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite right. For the `glm()` function in R, the `family=binomial` option defaults to a logistic regression. So, your residual calculation does not transform the residuals as you want.

You can use the `residuals.glm()` function to automatically generate the residuals for a generalized linear model in general. You can use the `residuals()` function for a linear model. Similarly, you can use the `predict()` function, instead of the `lm(x~z)$fitted.values` to get the xhats. However, since in this case you have xhat and x (not the same variable), use code close to your solution above (but using the `plogis()` function for the logit transformation):

```
stageOne <- lm(x ~ z)
xhat <- predict(stageOne)
stageTwo <- glm(y ~ xhat, family=binomial)
residuals <- y - plogis(stageTwo$coef[1] + stageTwo$coef[2]*x)
```

A nice feature of the `predict()` and `residuals()` or `residuals.glm()` functions is that they can be extended to other datasets.

Comment: Thanks for the nice command, but it gives me an error at the last step. 
(match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector) 
Here, x is the continuous variable (can't be a character)